# Case in update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to translate a talend code which has a nested IF statement into SQL

I thought I had translated it correctly, but no records are getting updated since the join condition fails. I added a top level case statement to check for existence of records, but wanted to double check from the experts here if my translation is correct at all.

Logic from Talend Mapper:

```
   IF row32.DISPLAY_NAME_REPORTED IS NULL THEN
     IF row31.REPORTED_DISPLAY_NAME IS NULL THEN
       IF row87.SPEC_TYPE1 IS NULL THEN
         IF row87.SPEC_TYPE2 IS null THEN
           row34.Series
         ELSE
           row34.Series + row34.Type2
         END
       ELSE
         row34.Series + row34.Type2
       END
     ELSE
       row31.REPORTED_DISPLAY_NAME
     END
   ELSE
     row32.DISPLAY_NAME_REPORTED  
   END
```

Corresponding case statement in SQL:

```
update a
        set a.seriesbt = case when exists (select 1 from  row32 x where 
           x.delivery_fk = a.delivery_fk) then
    case when b.delivery_fk is not null and 
                  b.DISPLAY_NAME_REPORTED is null then 
          case when c.reported_display_name is null then 
            case when d.SPEC_TYPE1 is null then
            case when d.SPEC_TYPE2 is null then
                    a.series 
                  else
                a.series+a.SPEC_TYPE2 end
            else a.series + a.SPEC_TYPE1 end 
             else c.reported_display_name end
        else b.DISPLAY_NAME_REPORTED end
    else a.series end
from tmpSales a 
left join row32 b on b.delivery_fk = a.delivery_fk 
left join row31 c  on c.DELIVERY_FK = a.delivery_fk 
left join row87 d on d.DELIVERY_FK = a.delivery_fk
```

Question is: Did I translate the talend mapper logic into SQL correctly? If not, can you please tell me what is wrong.
Should I be include "when exists" for each table? 
I thought the left join should implicitly handle it.

Comment: I noticed that some statements like "b.delivery_fk is not null" which are not in your logic. Did you post all of your logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have added an additional condition that was not in your original code. Coding the opposite way can make things simpler and avoid nested CASE expressions.

I changed your table alias to make it easier to understand where the columns come from without having to go back to the FROM clause.

```
UPDATE s
SET a.seriesbt = CASE WHEN r32.DISPLAY_NAME_REPORTED IS NOT NULL THEN r32.DISPLAY_NAME_REPORTED
                      WHEN r31.reported_display_name IS NOT NULL THEN r31.reported_display_name
                      WHEN r87.SPEC_TYPE1 IS NOT NULL THEN s.series /*row34.Series*/ + s.SPEC_TYPE1
                      WHEN r87.SPEC_TYPE2 IS NULL THEN s.series  --row34.Series
                      ELSE s.series /*row34.Series*/ + s.SPEC_TYPE2 
                      END
FROM tmpSales s 
LEFT JOIN row32 r32 ON r32.delivery_fk = s.delivery_fk 
LEFT JOIN row31 r31 ON r31.DELIVERY_FK = s.delivery_fk 
LEFT JOIN row87 r87 ON r87.DELIVERY_FK = s.delivery_fk;
```

I just realized that it could be simplified even more.

```
UPDATE s
SET a.seriesbt = COALESCE( r32.DISPLAY_NAME_REPORTED, 
                        r31.reported_display_name, 
                        s.series /*row34.Series*/ + s.SPEC_TYPE1, 
                        s.series /*row34.Series*/ + s.SPEC_TYPE2,
                        s.series  --row34.Series
                        )
FROM tmpSales s 
LEFT JOIN row32 r32 ON r32.delivery_fk = s.delivery_fk 
LEFT JOIN row31 r31 ON r31.DELIVERY_FK = s.delivery_fk 
LEFT JOIN row87 r87 ON r87.DELIVERY_FK = s.delivery_fk;
```